# NSURLSession blocks memory management

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

If I would recreate NSURLSession, would I be copying the block parameter passed into this function: -

```
- dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

To further illustrate, if I am writing NSURLSession, following ARC/Blocks best practices, should I copy the completionHandler passed into the above function, as they get called asynchronously (maybe after the stack has popped?).

Comment: Could you please give some extra explanation? What do you mean with your question?

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLSession` will copy those blocks itself.

So, no, you do not need to copy them. Note that if you elected to call `copy` on the completion handler, unless you yourself kept a reference to the copy, ARC would simply release the copy after you had "finished" with it, which would be immediately after the copy had been passed into the `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` function.

Also, there is only one completion handler passed into that method.

Comment: Right, so if I am writing my own NSURLSession, I should copy the block parameter passed ?

Comment: Yes. It would be exceedingly poor design to write a class that required the user to manage its resources. Also, I think it would be difficult to avoid doing so just as a consequence of keeping the block addressable -- all class properties that take a block are `copy`, and I think adding it to an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` will either implicitly copy the block, or refuse to compile until you do.